# Insert bold text into Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, excel

I wrote a little script that exports certain Excel cell values into Word. However, certain inserts need to be bold. And there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.

This code loops through the records and adds them to the Word document

```
Do While intRow < intTotalRows + 1

                strTemp = " ;b;" & Range("G" & intRow).FormulaR1C1 & " " & Range("I" & intRow).FormulaR1C1 & ";e; "

                If strTemp <> strCur Then
                    strCur = strTemp
                    .Content.Font.Bold = True
                    .Content.InsertAfter strCur
                End If

                .Content.Font.Bold = False
                .Content.InsertAfter Range("A" & intRow).FormulaR1C1 & " - " & Range("C" & intRow).FormulaR1C1 & " " & Range("E" & intRow).FormulaR1C1 & " * "

            intRow = intRow + 1
        Loop
```

Turning on bold before inserting text and turning it off again afterwards seems like the most logical solution, so it does not work.

I then tried to find and replace the text, but that also did not work:

```
        .Content.Find.ClearFormatting
        With .Content.Find
            .Text = ";b;" 'Look for
            .Replacement.Text = ";bbb;" 'Replace with
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False 
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False 
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
```

```
    .Content.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `.InsertAfter` with `.TypeText`. Inserting works like pasting whereas `TypeText` works like if you would actually type the text on the keyboard.