# How do I make some text bold, using Visual Basic in Excel to create a Word document?

Tags: vb6, excel-2003, word-2003

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966984/insert-bold-text-into-word-using-vba), but it doesn't work for me; I don't get where to change `insertafter` to `typetext`. What should I change in the following to make part of the text bold?

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
    With wrdDoc
        .Content.InsertAfter "not bold "
        .Content.Font.Bold = True
        .Content.InsertAfter "should be bold"
        .Content.Font.Bold = False
        .Content.InsertAfter " again not bold, followed by newline"
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        .Content.Font.Bold = True
        .Content.InsertAfter "bold again"
        .Content.Font.Bold = False
        .Content.InsertAfter " and again not bold"
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        .SaveAs ("testword.doc")
        .Close
    End With
    wrdApp.Quit
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `.Content.Font.Bold = True` and  `.Content.Font.Bold = False`, you're toggling the *entire* `Content` back and forth between bold and not bold. The last statement of this sort is `.Content.Font.Bold = False`, so of course nothing ends up being bold.

Here's a way to do what you want. It's really badly and quickly written but it should put you on the right track.

```
    .Content.InsertAfter "not bold "
    .Content.InsertAfter "should be bold"
    .Content.InsertAfter " again not bold, followed by newline"
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    .Content.InsertAfter "bold again"
    .Content.InsertAfter " and again not bold"
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter

    .Words(3).Font.Bold = True
    .Words(4).Font.Bold = True
    .Words(5).Font.Bold = True
    .Words(16).Font.Bold = True
    .Words(17).Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Now I just need to discover what gets counted as a word. Already found InsertParagraphAfter.